# Pull SQL value then run If/Else statement

Tags: c#, sql, if-statement

I want to take the value of agronomy either yes/no... if yes it opens another form if no it pops up a message box... just can't seem to wrap my head around how to pull that stored value from the SQL command.  Any help would be great I am sure it is something super simple...

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=*****;Initial Catalog=agSale;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT agronomy from logins where userName = @userName", cn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("userName", nameLabel.Text);
        cn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


        if (agronomy == "yes") 
             new agronomy().Show();
        else
            MessageBox.Show("You can't access this part of the program.  For questions call 867-5309.");


        cn.Close();
```

Comment: `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExecuteReader`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you just need a single value use `ExecuteScalar`:

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=*****;Initial Catalog=agSale;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT agronomy from logins where userName = @userName", cn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("userName", nameLabel.Text);
        cn.Open();
        string agronomy = cmd.ExecuteScalar()?.ToString();


        if (agronomy == "yes") 
             new agronomy().Show();
        else
            MessageBox.Show("You can't access this part of the program.  For questions call 867-5309.");


        cn.Close();
```

Comment: I have the user in the database and under agronomy is set to yes... however it pops up the message box.... wonder what it would be missing?

Comment: What is the result if you run the SQL Statement in SSMS? Whats the value of `agronomy` in the `if` statement?

Comment: Just ran it and it comes back as yes for that username

Comment: And if you set a breakpoint on the "if" line then what is the value of agronomy?

Comment: `(If agronomy.Trim() == "yes")` fixed the issue